# Is my home folder encrypted?

Tags: linux, encryption, home

Is there a way to check if my home folder is encrypted? I believe I checked this option during the installation, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Which distro? In Ubuntu, try: `cat /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the distro, I will describe the method for Ubuntu (and maybe its derivatives) 
Try looking for folders **$HOME/.Private** and **$HOME/.ecryptfs**. Any one or both should be present.
or try `ls -A /home` this should give an output mentioning either one or both the two folders.

Source: [EncryptedHome - Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome)